# Get right output from for loop when in function

Tags: r

I know there may be more elegant to do this - but right now I just want to grok this logic...
My problem is that when I do a typical `Y[t]=Y[t-1]+i[t]` thing for simulation it does not work when put in a function.
I want to have a data frame out with the correct variable value on each row for time or t 1-10.
Now the cat inside the loop reveals I am going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
iter <- 10; i <- rep(0.1,iter);  
i <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0)
Y0 <- 0.25 ; O0 <- 4.16 
Y <- rep(0,iter); O <- rep(0,iter) 
Tot <- rep(0,iter)
t <- seq(1,iter) #start time and fill vector
Y[1]=Y0 #First iter
O[1]=O0
Tot[1]= Y0+O0
time<-rep(1,iter)#runtime unit

#This is a simplified version of the ICBM function, to test the logic and output
Isim <- function(i, h, Y0, O0,iter,time) {
  for (t in 2:iter) {
    time<- time+1
    Y[t]=(Y[t-1]+i[t-1]); O[t]=(O[t-1]+i[t-1]); Tot[t]=Y[t]+O[t];
    simout <- data.frame(i,Y0,O0,Y,O,Tot,time)
    cat(time)
  } 
  return(simout)
}

result <- Isim(i, h, Y0, O0,iter, time)
```

Comment: What is `time` doing there, despite being increase by 1? You really shouldn't use a `for` loop for this. It's very easy to use a vectorized approach here and it will be faster by some orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

(Let's make abstraction of the fact your code cannot run.) You have a scoping issue at the `Y[t]=(Y[t-1]+i[t-1])` step. Let's look at a small reproducible example:

```
increment_a <- function() { a <- a + 1; print(a); }
a <- 0; print(a); increment_a(); print(a);
# [1] 0 # ok
# [1] 1 # ok
# [1] 0 # not what you expected
```

Inside `increment_a`, when R computes `a + 1`, it first looks for `a` in the function's environment. That environment being empty, it then looks for `a` in the environment from which the function was called: your global environment. It finds it there, with a value of `0`. It adds `1` to that `0` and then goes to assign it (the `a <-` part of the statement) **in the local environment**, i.e. the function's environment.

How can you solve this? You could tell R to assign the result of `a + 1` to the `a` found in the global environment: use `<<-` instead of `<-`:

```
increment_a <- function() { a <<- a + 1; print(a); }
a <- 0; print(a); increment_a(); print(a);
# [1] 0
# [1] 1
# [1] 1
```

**BUT** this is not recommended. It is dangerous and will cause you troubles down the line. Instead, you need to fully embrace the functional programming style. I suggest you read the first paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming, especially the part about functions not having side effects. This is how things work:

1. make your function only use objects that are passed to it as arguments.
2. make use of the function's output(s) via the `return` statement.
3. Do not make your function have side-effect, in particular, do not use `<<-`.
4. if your function needs to modify objects: pass them as arguments, make your function modify them and return them. Then re-assign the result as in:

```
increment <- function(x) { x <- x + 1; print(x); return(x); }
a <- 0; print(a); a <- increment(a); print(a);
# [1] 0
# [1] 1
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Wow, two quick replies. Thanks lots. I will now pour a cup of coffee, put on a tinfoil hat and try to improve and correct. R is fun - but it takes some effort to forget old ways...

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one of us did answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, instead of `time<- time+1`, try to use `time[t] <- t`..

When you increment `time` by `1` in each iteration, you end with the vector:

```
    time
    [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

which is the final input in `simout`.

`simout$time` is altered in each iteration as follows:

```
    2 2 2 2 ... 
    3 3 3 3 ...
    ...
    10 10 10 ...
```

so you should change only a specific element of `time` in each iteration.

Now (you can see it from `cat`) `simout$time` changes as:

```
    1 1 1 1 ...
    1 2 1 1 ...
    1 2 3 1 ...
    ...
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 #this is the final input in "simout"
```